# "Empli" vs "rempli"

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, synonymes

Couramment, quelle est la différence entre *un cylindre empli de fluide* et *un cylindre rempli de fluide* ? Pourquoi *remplir* a remplacé *emplir* bien que les deux verbes n'aient pas le même sens selon [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/emplir) ? Pourquoi [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/emplir/28954) considère « emplir » comme littéraire ?

Comment: Je crois, s'il n'y a pas d'erreur, que jlliagre pense que ce doit être « ont », le présent. Ce que j'ai toujours su est que « bien que » est suivi du subjonctif, et cela  est confirmé par la BDL :«« bien que »
exige généralement le subjonctif. ». Cependant, les points de vue ont changé ; on met en doute beaucoup de concepts dans le domaine de la grammaire, comme par exemple le conditionnel qui ne serait même plus un mode. Alors on ne sait pas trop ce qui est vraiment solide, logique, vrai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complément de réponse

Pourquoi « remplir » a-t-il remplacé « emplir » ? C'est une de ces questions du type dont les réponses sont habituellement cachées dans un domaine insondable et que l'on ne peut oser considérer sans percevoir combien est vaine notre recherche. Je n'ai pas de réponse pour celle-ci mais elle est particulière en cela que ses termes mêmes donnent une clé possible à sa réponse ; ceci est pure spéculation de ma part. Peut être que en un âge assez reculé, lorsque l'eau courante n'était pas encore une des commodités de la vie et qu'il fallait avoir recours à des porteurs d'eau, à des puits et des sources, une grande partie de l'occupation en ce qui concernait la préservation d'une fourniture d'eau dans les habitations consistait à re-emplir des récipients et les gens entendaient beaucoup le terme « re-emplir », très vite « remplir », ce qu'ils auraient assimilé très rapidement et irrémédiablement à l'action d'emplir dans n'importe quelle circonstance.

Pourquoi « emplir » est-il un mot littéraire ? Une explication assez logique, vu qu'il existe un autre mot pour le même contexte pourrait être tout simplement qu'il a été oublié dans la langue parlée, comme elle est peut être mieux perpétuée par la langue parlée elle-même que par la langue littéraire, en particulier pour les concepts courants. Il est très difficile de juger de ces phénomènes-là ; je ne crois pas que la socio-linguistique ait pu déterminer des principes tant soit peu fiables pour expliquer ces choses ou que des principes aient été dégagés à partir d'études au cas par cas ; je n'en ai jamais entendu parler.

Answer (score 6):

Les verbes sont synonymes mais dans certains cas ils ne sont pas interchangeables.
Dans le cas de emplir/remplir, le r ne signifie pas "re-emplir"; c'est plus subtil.

Les acceptations communes d'emplir et de remplir:

1. Rendre plein par sa présence une portion d'espace: les spectateurs peuvent emplir / remplir une salle.
2. Rendre plein un réceptacle: on peut emplir / remplir un cylindre.
3. Rendre "plein" d'un sentiment: on peut emplir / remplir de joie, d'amour...

Les acceptations supplémentaires de remplir :

1. Couvrir entièrement un support visuel, compléter un document: on peut remplir une page, un formulaire; mais pas les emplir.
2. Exercer une fonction, accomplir: on peut remplir une fonction, un rôle, une condition, une obligation; mais pas les emplir.

Comment: _Dans le cas de emplir/remplir, le r ne signifie pas "re-emplir"; c'est plus subtil._ ... Et pourtant il s'agit de la première définition du TLFi pour **remplir** : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/remplir